# Merging 2 Pivot Tables together using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to merge 2 pivot tables together into 1 using VBA?

I am quite new to VBA, I have only started using it 2 months ago. Right now, I have Pivot Table A from sheet 'A' Data and Pivot Table B from sheet 'B' Data. There are a few similarities in the data but not completely. Additionally, the amount of data differs. I would like to merge the Pivot Table A and Pivot Table B based on the months in the data into a new Pivot Table. Do let me know if there is a way around it:) Thank you in advance!

I have tried merging the 2 data but it was not an ideal option.

Comment: You cannot merge 2 pivot tables. You can use VBA to write some code to copy the relevant data to another range (and create a 3rd pivot table if you need its functionality). Please share the screenshots of sheets `A` and `B` and of the desired result. Also, share what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Hello, I am unable to share the screenshots of sheets A and B but I can explain what it contains. they contain the sales done by the team for the year. By referring to the sales funnel, Sheet B will be containing the data from Opportunities while Sheet A will be for Quotations. My pivot table produced by Sheet B will be using the date created and grouping them by months for rows and the BQ for col (therefore there will only be one col). My pivot table A will be consisting the sales status in the cols and date created by months for rows. The similarity is the date created.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Could you explain your VBA solution pls? Thank you